# Create a sysv init script with upstart/systemd detection

Tags: linux, init, upstart, systemd

I'm trying to create a common set of init scripts for Ubuntu upstart/Debian SysV and systemd systems.

I realize for upstart, I can always just have a simple check in my `/etc/init.d/appname` file:

```
. /lib/lsb/init-functions
check_for_upstart() {
    if init_is_upstart; then
        echo "Upstarted detected. Use upstart service commands. Exiting." >&2
        exit 1
    fi
}
```

(or I could get fancier and forward relevant commands to upstart, as some Ubuntu scripts do)

Is there a similar way to detect if systemd is in use and either exit or redirect to systemctl? I realize a lot of openSUSE scripts redirect to systemctl, but looking at the scripts, I don't understand exactly how they do this. I'm guessing it's via the `/etc/rc_status` file they include, but this appears to be openSUSE specific and doesn't apply to CentOS.

Ultimately I want to support Ubuntu 14, Debian 7, CentOS/RHEL 7 and openSUSE (any systemd). So my systemv init script would really only be for Debian, and would just exist with a message on every other distro (or redirect to systemctl/upstart in some standard way).

Are there any examples/best practices out there for achieving this?

Comment: Debian and Ubuntu do the redirection via init-functions. Do not know about CentOS/RHEL.

Comment: Hey, take a look [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/121654/convenient-way-to-check-if-system-is-using-systemd-or-sysvinit-in-bash), [there](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18209/detect-init-system-using-the-shell) and [over there](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18209/detect-init-system-using-the-shell)

Comment: Don't install init or upstart scripts on systemd systems. Problem solved.